# Change password value in the database each time log in

Tags: php, security

Is it a good way to change password value each time a user log in to the database?
I have wrote a hash function to hash the password when a user register a new account on the system.
Each time the user logs in, the hash value in the database will be changed. Is it good or bad?

Comment: It depends on how you do it. Can we see some code?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Unless you can come up with a specific scenario, it sounds like that would just add complexity without any security benefit.

Comment: Sounds too obsessive... if someone can crack the 1st hash implementation who's to say they can't crack the nth?

Comment: @John I get the sample code from alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql and I edit it a little.

Comment: @Kitsune each time a user log in, the password hash value in the database will be changed with the session key.

Comment: @EricFleischman the question was, is it good or bad. actually it is not a problem if I don't change the password hash value. I just want to know whether this will increase the security or not. if not well, I would to know the better approaching in web/PHP security.

Answer (score 1):

If you designed this hash function all by your self then... It is a very very bad idea. Why would you need something like this? If you store salted SHA-256 hashed passwords the security is good enough. You do not need to regenerate passwords, it does not provide any additional security. If lets say your app is prone to SQL-Injection, then this scheme won't protect your app. You would be a lot better if you used salted and keyed SHA-256, something like this: (I'm not a php coder, I just want our apps to be secure)

```
$username = 'Admin';
$password = 'gf45_gdf#4hg';
$key = 'MySuperSecretKEY!!!!';
$salt = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) . 'something random' . strtolower($username));
$hash = $salt . $password . $key;
$hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
$hash = $salt . $hash;
```

and then checking:

```
$username = 'Admin';
$password = 'gf45_gdf#4hg';

$sql = '
  SELECT
    `hash`
  FROM `users`
    WHERE
      `username` = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . '"
  LIMIT 1
  ;';

$r = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));

$salt = substr($r['hash'], 0, 64);
$hash = $salt . $password . $key;
$hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
$hash = $salt . $hash;

if ( $hash == $r['hash'] ) {
  //OK
}
```

So even if attacker will be able to trick the salting algorithm he does not know, a key so he won't be able to reproduce a valid hash in SQL-Injection attack.

Comment: sorry, I mean I got the sample hashing then I modified it a little. this is the source http://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/ I'm quite new in PHP and really would like to learn a lot from this. any kind of help would be appreciated. thanks :D

Comment: It's a good idea to use a different salt for each user, it increases the time it takes to crack databases of passwords by a lot, since a generated hash can really only be used to check one account.

Comment: @Wizzard yes I know, but is it good to change the hash value each time a user log in? When a user log in, I call the hashing function to hash the password again and each time they log in the database value will be changed but the raw password is the same